# Синтаксические ошибки

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <conio.h> 
#define eof -1 

#define yes 1
#define no 0

int main()

{    
    int c;
    int nc;
    int n1;
    int nw;
    int in;
    nc=n1=nw=0;
    in=no;
    printf("Enter your strings and press <Enter> >\n");
    while((c=getchar()) !=eof)
    {
        if(c !='\n')
            nc++;
        else
            n1++;
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t')
            in no;
        else if(in=no)
        {
            in yes;
            nw++;
        }
        else
            ;
    }

    printf("Strings...=%d\n",n1);
    printf("Words...=%d\n",nw);
    printf("Characters...=d\n",nc);
    _getch();
}
```

Компилятор выдает следующие ошибки:

> error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "константа"
>
> error C2181: недопустимый else без парного if
>
> error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "константа"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in no
in yes
```

нет присваивания

```
in=no
in=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

И еще

```
else if(in=no)
        {
            in yes;
            nw++;
        }
```

Всегда будет входить в if если no не равно нулю.

Comment: Нормальный компилятор на такие хохмы предупреждения выдаёт.

Comment: ну хз, gcc без -Wall молча скомпилил

Comment: Увы, да. Вывод -- не забывать -Wall. gcc заодно и насчёт третьего printf предупреждение выдал (там в формате вместо `%d` стоит `d`)